# Where are the Laplacian Lightning settings once the addon has been installed?

Tags: add-on

I broke down and installed the Laplacian Lightning addon, like suggested. But now I can't find where to trigger it, that is to say, actually apply it to an object like a plane.

In specific, this plane:[image]

I don't really have any ideas on where the button might be, but then again, I only got it yesterday. Can I have some help please?

Comment: And Ray? Please, stop editing the title, they're meant to be a hook to get people to notice it.

Comment: The purpose of the title is to indicate what the body of the question will be  (which I didn't think your title did) not to 'hook' people. The purpose of this site is to not only answer questions but to provide a database of answers that might be found via google by others, in the future, which might be hard if the title is not perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1):

From the addon author's [website](http://funkboxing.com/wordpress/?p=301):

> UI will be in >View3D>Tool Shelf>Laplacian Lightning (object mode)

Make it appear by pressing <kbd>T</kbd> (View>Tool shelf) while in 3d view and scroll down to the menu in the Tools tab. It is visible only in Object mode.

If this doesn't work, make sure you downloaded the proper version that match the current Blender version. See [the website](http://funkboxing.com/wordpress/?p=301) fore more details.

Comment: ummm.... shiitake mushrooms! sorry, umm... blender's... dying. Really. It's not letting me scroll. Something's horribly horribly wrong.

Comment: I'll mark you as answer once the issue is fixed.