# Boids Aerial March

Tags: animation, modifiers, particles

Well, I think I just did something hella awesome.

Remember that question about the lightning that got closed, as well as the sudden closing? (see [Where are the Laplacian Lightning settings once the addon has been installed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33418/where-are-the-laplacian-lightning-settings-once-the-addon-has-been-installed), [Blender closes when using the scroll wheel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33464/blender-closes-when-using-the-scroll-wheel), https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33262/are-particle-emitters-a-good-starting-point-for-creating-lightning)

Well, Laplacian Lightning didn't work out one bit. Whenever I tried to use the scroll wheel on the mouse, Blender suddenly closed. I'll have to find another way... and I think I'm onto something.

I present to you, the nova:[image][image][image]
This was done solely by assigning a particle emmission system using Boids physics to have metaball particles.

It's not the snazziest, but it's pretty darn cool. However, it has given me an idea: what if I had the boids particles move in (relatively) as straight line?

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't know what effects are you really trying to achieve, but I can tell you that in boid's option you can add a GOAL rule. If it is predominant on the other effects should bring the boids to move toward a defined object in a straight line

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks! I try to keep the titles engaging, to try to boost views.

Comment: I'm trying to create a lightning effect from scratch because Laplacian Lightning completely broke Blender. In specific, this is an attempt to emulate the Red/Green Miles of Homestuck.